# Paging in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to implement paging using Row_Number() method in this query but with no luck.

The following Query uses recursive way to get Sites for a set of categories.

```
    WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
   WHERE yt.ID = @topicID And CultureID = @cultureID 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
    JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ParentCategoryID)
    Select id, [SiteName]
      ,[SiteURL]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Logo]
      ,[CultureID]
      ,[DateAdded],  dbo.GetSiteFollowers(id) AS Followers from dbo.TH_Sites where id in (
 Select Distinct SiteID from dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds Where CatID in (
   SELECT ID
    FROM hierarchy t   ))
```

This query returns all the sites for a set of categories. I am trying to integrate Row_Number() to the dbo.TH_Sites table so I can get x number of records for each request using the

```
Where RowNumber BETWEEN @rowStart AND @rowEnd
```

But I keep getting T-SQL errors.

Any tips guys, thanks.

I am trying this :

```
    WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
   WHERE yt.ID = @topicID And CultureID = @cultureID 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.id

    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
    JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ParentCategoryID)

    Select id, [SiteName]
      ,[SiteURL]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Logo]
      ,[CultureID]
      ,[DateAdded], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [DateAdded] DESC) AS 'RowNumber' ,  dbo.GetSiteFollowers(id) AS Followers from dbo.TH_Sites where RowNumber = 5  AND  id in (
 Select Distinct SiteID from dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds Where CatID in (
   SELECT ID
    FROM hierarchy t))
```

But I am getting RowNumber is not a valid column

Here is another Implementation :

```
WITH hierarchy AS (
```

SELECT yt.id

```
FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
```

WHERE yt.ID = @topicID And CultureID = @cultureID 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.id

```
FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ParentCategoryID)
WITH numbered_hierarchy AS (
Select id, [SiteName]
  ,[SiteURL]
  ,[Description]
  ,[Logo]
  ,[CultureID]
  ,[DateAdded] , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [DateAdded] DESC) AS 'RowNumber',  dbo.GetSiteFollowers(id) AS Followers from dbo.TH_Sites where  id in (
```

Select Distinct SiteID from dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds Where CatID in (
   SELECT ID
    FROM hierarchy t )) )

```
 SELECT id
     , [SiteName]
     , [SiteURL]
     , [Description]
     , [Logo]
     , [CultureID]
     , [DateAdded]
     , RowNumber
     , Followers
FROM numbered_hierarchy
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

Comment: "But I keep getting T-SQL errors"   Please post?  That's usually the juiciest part. :)

Comment: When I hoop-up  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [DateAdded] DESC) AS 'RowNumber' as an additional column for dbo.TH_Sites and add RowNumber Between 1 AND 5 to the where close of 'from dbo.TH_Sites where id in ...' 

I get that RowNumber is not a valid column.

Comment: can you put this SQL in your question?

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `ROW_NUMBER()` function into your CTE:

```
WITH YourCTE AS
(
   SELECT (list of fields),
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ......) AS 'RowNum'
) 
SELECT (list of fields), RowNum
FROM YourCTE
```

Once you do that, you can easily select certain rows from the CTE:

```
WITH YourCTE AS
(
   SELECT (list of fields),
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ......) AS 'RowNum'
) 
SELECT (list of fields), RowNum
FROM YourCTE
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 51 AND 75  -- or something like that
```

Not sure how that'll work with recursive CTE's though (I don't have SQL Server at hand right now to test this).

Comment: The paging is at the level of a nested table called dbo.TH_Sites.

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't allow the use of column aliases in a WHERE clause. Instead, put the `RowNumber` calculation into your CTE:

```
WITH numbered_rows AS (
    SELECT s.id
         , s.[SiteName]
         , s.[SiteURL]
         , s.[Description]
         , s.[Logo]
         , s.[CultureID]
         , s.[DateAdded]
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by s.[DateAdded] DESC) AS [RowNumber]
         , dbo.GetSiteFollowers(s.id) AS [Followers]
    FROM dbo.TH_Sites s
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT SiteID
        FROM dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds cf
        INNER JOIN dbo.TH_Categories c ON c.ID = cf.CatID
        WHERE (c.ID = @topicID OR c.ParentCategoryID = @topicID)
            AND c.CultureID = @cultureID
    ) feeds ON feeds.SiteID = s.ID
)

SELECT id
     , [SiteName]
     , [SiteURL]
     , [Description]
     , [Logo]
     , [CultureID]
     , [DateAdded]
     , RowNumber
     , Followers
FROM numbered_rows
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @rowStart AND @rowEnd
```

**EDIT: Eliminated the `hierarchy` CTE.**

**EDIT: Modified the JOINs to use a sub-query.**

Comment: In addition, you could probably get away with using JOINs instead of WHERE...IN.

Comment: When I hook up another CTE to the query I get this error : 

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @Joseph - You comma delimit them. e.g. `;With tl as (select...), t2 as (select...) select * from t1 join t2...`

Comment: Sorry jeff, but can u modify the query u've post it so I can have an idea what u intend to do. thanks for the help.

Comment: @Joseph: Oops. Don't know quite what I was thinking there. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your help. But I am getting the redundant data. The first query I wrote in my post returns the correct number of Sites which are 53. Now your query returns 36 with duplicates sites.

hmmm, Seems it is tough to solve.

Comment: @Joseph: I modified the CTE to use a sub-query for the relationship between feeds and categories. Does that work?

Comment: RowNumber works perfectly but I am getting only 16 Rows where the Category 45 has 56 Sites. But the RowNumber works correctly.

Comment: When I mean Category 45 has 56 sites that means 45 and all its descendant ( all Cats that has ParentCategoryID = 45 and so on ).

Answer (score 0):

Edited:  Added the distinct in the final select incase the join to cte was giving multiple records.

Try this, I think its what your going for.

```
;with hierarchy 
as
(
    select 
        yt.id

    from 
        dbo.TH_Categories yt

    where 
        yt.ID = @topicID 
        and CultureID = @cultureID 

    union

    select 
        parent.id as id

    from 
        dbo.TH_Categories yt
        left join dbo.th_categories parent
            on yt.id = parent.parentcategoryid
    order by dateadded desc
)

select distinct
    ths.id 
    ,ths.[SiteName]
    ,ths.[SiteURL]
    ,ths.[Description]
    ,ths.[Logo]
    ,ths.[CultureID]
    ,ths.[DateAdded],  
    dbo.GetSiteFollowers(ths.id) AS Followers 

from 
    dbo.TH_Sites ths
    join dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds cf
        on ths.id = cf.siteid
    join 
        (
            select
                id
                ,row_number() as RowNumber
            from
                hierarchy 
        ) h on cf.catid = h.id

where
    h.rownumber = 5;
```

Comment: It is close, but I am getting for rownumber = 5   6 records.

so it is not accurate.

Comment: RowNumber  Between 1 and 5 is getting 16 Rows.

Comment: I added a distinct on to the final select in case the category feeds is giving multiple records on the join.  Not sure of your table scema.

Comment: Sorry, but the query is broken. with distinct it is getting 4 rows whatever the rownumber is

Answer (score 0):

This query returns all the sites :

```
WITH hierarchy AS (
```

SELECT yt.id

```
FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
```

WHERE yt.ID = @topicID And CultureID = @cultureID 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.id

```
FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ParentCategoryID)

Select id, [SiteName]
  ,[SiteURL]
  ,[Description]
  ,[Logo]
  ,[CultureID]
  ,[DateAdded], dbo.GetSiteFollowers(id) AS Followers from dbo.TH_Sites where  id in (
```

Select Distinct SiteID from dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds Where CatID in (
   SELECT ID
    FROM hierarchy t ))

I just need to implement paging to this query. is it that difficult ?

Come on T-SQL GURUS !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT yt.id
    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
    WHERE yt.ID = @topicID AND CultureID = @cultureID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT yt.id
    FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
    JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ParentCategoryID
)
SELECT id
    , [SiteName]
    , [SiteURL]
    , [Description]
    , [Logo]
    , [CultureID]
    , [DateAdded]
    , dbo.GetSiteFollowers(id) AS Followers
FROM dbo.TH_Sites
WHERE id in
(
    SELECT DISTINCT SiteID
    FROM dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds
    WHERE CatID IN ( SELECT ID FROM hierarchy t )
)
AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateAdded] DESC) BETWEEN @rowStart AND @rowEnd
ORDER BY [DateAdded] DESC
```

Comment: I am getting this :

Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Jeff, it is a tough Coconut :)

Comment: Yes, it is, and I'm out of ideas. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH hierarchy AS 
(
     SELECT yt.id    
       FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
      WHERE yt.ID = @topicID And CultureID = @cultureID
     UNION ALL
     SELECT yt.id    
       FROM [dbo].[TH_Categories] yt
       JOIN hierarchy h ON h.ID = yt.ParentCategoryID
)
, YourRows AS 
(
    Select id, 
           [SiteName]
          ,[SiteURL]
          ,[Description]
          ,[Logo]
          ,[CultureID]
          ,[DateAdded]
          ,dbo.GetSiteFollowers(id) AS Followers 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateAdded] DESC) AS RowNumber
     from dbo.TH_Sites 
    where id in (Select Distinct SiteID 
                   from dbo.TH_CategoryFeeds 
                  Where CatID in (SELECT ID
                                    FROM hierarchy t ))
)
SELECT * FROM YourRows 
WHERE RowNumber>=@rowStart and RowNumber<=@rowEnd
```